# div background color change based on div size CSS (use in bootstrap 4 carousel)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, bootstrap-4

I want to change the background color of a div based on Height percentage (different colors) with CSS (no gradient color)

the reason I look for such a thing in CSS is that I tried to write a code to handle the background color of div based on div CSS Height percentage **with animations of course** ( something like a progress bar )

my code runs perfectly but I want it to use in the bootstrap 4 carousel

that's my problem ( in bootstrap 4 carousel my code runs only one time)

all of the contents use that code plays together

I want to play them separately in bootstrap 4 carousel

here is my code

```js
;(function (document, $) {
  
  $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.rating-bar').each(function () {
      var _this = $(this),
        size = _this.data('size');
  
      _this.animate({
        height: size + '%'
      }, {
        duration: 2500,
        step: function (progress) {
          _this.css({
            backgroundColor: progressColor(progress)
          });
        }
      });
    });
  });
  
  function progressColor(progress) {
    if (progress >= 0 && progress <= 24) return '#ff3051';
    else if (progress >= 25 && progress <= 49) return '#ffb200';
    else if (progress >= 50 && progress <= 74) return '#77b5fe';
    else if (progress >= 75 && progress <= 89) return '#00cfae';
    else if (progress >= 90 && progress <= 100) return '#00ff87';
  }
  })(document, jQuery);
```

```css
.rating-bar {
    outline: none;
    -moz-border-radius:20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    -moz-transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
    -webkit-transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
    transition: background-color 0.5s linear 0s;
  box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px #000000;
  border-bottom: 3px solid #dee2e6
}

.rating-bar-bg-overall {
    height: 100%;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    -webkit-border-radius:20px;
    border-radius:20px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.rating-cont{
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
position: absolute;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
border-radius:20px;
z-index: -1;
transform: rotate(180deg);
  -webkit-transform: rotate(180deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(180deg); 
}

.rating-cont li{
list-style: none;
box-shadow: 0px 3px 8px #aaa, inset 0px 2px 3px #fff;
background-color: #fff;
border: 3px solid #dee2e6;
-moz-border-radius: 20px;
-webkit-border-radius:20px;
border-radius:20px;
}

.per-lft{

    position: absolute;
    width: 90%;height: 90%;
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -ms-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  -webkit-transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul class="rating-cont">
                    <li class="rating-bar-bg-overall per-lft"><div class="rating-bar" data-size="19"></div></li>
                    <li class="rating-bar-bg-overall per-off"><div class="rating-bar" data-size="80"></div></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Can you post another snippet with the carousel you want? And what do you mean by "runs only once"

Comment: Hi, is your question how to use CSS for the animation rather than what you do now with JavaScript (via jquery)?

Comment: thanks but I already solve my problem on my own